# How to handle websocket requests parallel?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, websocket

I have a standard websocket-endpoint build in java on glassfish. If I send an asyncronus long-running request to it, followed directly by an independent quick-running 2nd request, the 2nd request isn't run until the 1st request finished.

To solve this I forked a Thread for each incomming request:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/mysocket")
public class my_WebSocket {
  @OnMessage
  public void onMessage(Session session) {
    Thread t = new Thread(){
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try{
          doWork(session);
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
      }
    };
    t.start();
  }
  // ...
}
```

According to my application behaviour and logfile-output the requests are handled in parallel now. Unfortunately the overall runtime of these solution is (exactly) the same as the original version without threads. For me this is an indicator that the requests internally are still processed in serial.

**Question:**

How can I configure glassfish to handle the threads correctly? Since I found some posts that using Threads in the backend is considered "bad": Is there a better solution to handle different requests to a websocket from one client in parallel?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29520391/have-tomcat-handle-websocket-calls-in-parallel-using-different-threads) discusses the Topic on Tomcat, but without solution...

**UPDATE**

It turned out the requests were running parallel. The thing "serializing" my requests were the database-connection which was shared between all requests...